# SML Polymorphic references in signatures

Tags: reference, functional-programming, polymorphism, sml

Is there a way to make polymorphic references constants in signatures?

This code compiles, but is not what I need:

```
signature NAME = sig
    type 'a name
    val empty : 'a name
end

structure Name :> NAME  = struct
    datatype 'a name = Nil | Val of 'a
    val empty = Nil
end
```

Adding the required references:

```
signature NAME = sig
    type 'a name
    val empty : 'a name ref
end

structure Name :> NAME  = struct
    datatype 'a name = Nil | Val of 'a
    val empty = ref Nil
end
```

Produces the following error:

```
error: Structure does not match signature.
    Signature: val empty: 'a name ref
    Structure: val empty: 'a name ref
    Reason: Can't match 'a to 'a (Type variable is free in surrounding scope)
Found near struct datatype 'a name = Nil | Val of 'a  val empty = ref Nil end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't actually have to do with signatures; you'd get the same sort of issue if you wrote (at top-level):

```
val emptyListRef = ref nil
val emptyIntList = (! emptyListRef) : int list
val emptyStringList = (! emptyListRef) : string list
```

The issue is that `emptyListRef` — or in your case `empty` — can't be polymorphic. (Your compiler claims that `empty` has type `'a name ref`, but what it *really* means is that `empty` will have some type of the form `?? name ref`, and it hasn't yet figured out what `??` will be.)

This restriction makes sense when you consider that if `empty` *were* polymorphic, then you'd be able to write things like:

```
val () = empty := Val 3
val Val (x : string) = !empty
```

where you set `empty` to hold an `int Name` and then read from it as if it held a `string Name`. There's no way the convince the compiler to trust that you won't do that.

The general rule is that value bindings are only allowed to be polymorphic if the right-hand side takes one of a few simple forms, like combinations of constructors (other than `ref`!) and constants and `fn`-expressions, that are known to be safe (in that they can't enable the above-described misbehavior). This rule is called the *[value restriction](https://www.google.com/search?q=value+restriction)*; you can Google that term to get much more information.

Comment: Thanks! I was getting confused because `datatype 'a name = Nil | Val of 'a val h = ref Nil val _ = h := Val 5` doesn't produce an error, but this does: `datatype 'a name = Nil | Val of 'a val h = ref Nil; val _ = h := Val 5` (notice the semicolon)

Comment: @zlotnleo: You're welcome! As for why a semicolon makes a difference -- the *Definition of Standard ML* doesn't really say how the compiler should handle a declaration for a non-generalizable binding like `empty = ref Nil`. It seems that your compiler lets the binding sort of "hang" for a bit, waiting to get more information so that it can infer the type of `empty`. Once it reaches the semicolon (which ends the top-level declaration), your compiler apparently gives up on that (either returning an error, or assigning a default or dummy type, or something).